# Scroll by a "pageful" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scroll

I can't seem to find any reference to an event/method that would allow me to programaticaly mimic the scroll that occurs when you simply click below a dragger, on the scrollbar rail.
Is there a way to do that?

**Edit:**

Below please find illustration of the problem.

[image: Scrollbar paging areas]

The highlighted area is the scrollbar rail where, by clicking, you scroll by a "pageful" amount calculated by the browser. I am after mimicking a click in these areas, something like `.scrollByPageUp()` / `.scrollByPageDown()`.

The reference to a scroll plugin does not seem to provide a way to do that. Specifically, a method `.scroll(int)` would need a sensible integer to be passed in. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: Can you provide an example..

Comment: I have attached a screenshot to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

scrollTo should do what you are looking for

http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/